# Spotify app api - Track listing of a temporary playlist

Tags: api, spotify, playlist, temporary

I'm trying to list the tracks included in a temporary playlist.
but I get this message when rendering my view :
 Uncaught Error: Invalid playlist URI: spotify:internal:temp_playlist:spotify:app:XXX@1178994458541

here is my code : 
    var pl = models.Playlist.fromURI(tpl.uri);
    var list = new views.List(pl);
    document.body.appendChild(list.node);

is there a way to do this ?

Many Thanks,

Comment: here is how I create my temporary playlist :var tpl = sp.core.getTemporaryPlaylist(temporaryName());

Comment: Regarding the comment above, any API starting sp.core is private and will not be allowed into the App Finder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to use temporary playlists is like this:

`var myTemporaryPlaylist = new models.Playlist();`

Then add tracks, etc to it. When are you trying to use the URI to get the playlist back? Temporary playlists go away when the client is exited, etc.